# How can I generate and randomly assign color to annular sectors?

Tags: graphics, random

[image]

How can I generate such an image and fill every annular sector with a random colour?

Comment: `ParametricPlot[r {Cos[t], Sin[t]}, {t, 0, 2 Pi}, {r, 0, 5}, 
 MeshShading -> {{Red, Blue}, {Yellow, Green}}]` ?

Comment: Related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/10923/understanding-pie-chart-annulus-generation-and-alternate-style-using-disk

Answer (score 18, accepted):

With **V10** came `RandomColor` and `ColorSpace`

Using **Michael E2**'s wonderful solution

```
plot =
  ParametricPlot[r {Cos[t], Sin[t]}, {r, 0, 12}, {t, 0, 2 Pi},
   ImageSize -> 500,
   Mesh -> 13,
   MeshShading -> {{Red, Red}, {Red, Red}},
   PlotRange -> {{-9, 9}, {-4, 4}}];

Grid @ Partition[Table[plot /.
    poly_Polygon :> {RandomColor[ColorSpace -> space], poly},
         {space, {"RGB", "XYZ", "CMYK", "Grayscale"}}], 2]
```

[image]

Comment: eldo, just saw this.. Neat (+1)

Comment: @eldo very nice...thank you for introducing me to `RandomColor` and `ColorSpace` :)

Answer (score 19):

Hmm...Szabolcs beat me to it (in a comment) by one minute...

```
plot = ParametricPlot[r {Cos[t], Sin[t]}, {r, 0, 12}, {t, 0, 2 Pi}, 
   Mesh -> 23, Axes -> False, 
   MeshShading -> {{Red, Green}, {Blue, Yellow}}, 
   PlotRange -> {{-9, 9}, {-4, 4}}];

plot /. poly_Polygon :> {RGBColor @@ RandomReal[1, 3], poly}
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 15):

Making the `MeshShading` setting `Dynamic` also works without the need for post-processing:

```
ParametricPlot[r {Cos[t], Sin[t]}, {r, 0, 12}, {t, 0, 2 Pi},
 Mesh -> 23, Axes -> False,
 MeshShading -> Dynamic@{{Hue@RandomReal[], Hue@RandomReal[]},
                         {Hue@RandomReal[], Hue@RandomReal[]}}, 
 PlotRange -> {{-9, 9}, {-4, 4}}]
```

[image]

The same trick works in combination with V10 `RandomColor`:

```
ParametricPlot[r {Cos[t], Sin[t]}, {r, 0, 12}, {t, 0, 2 Pi},
  Mesh -> 23, Axes -> False,BaseStyle->Opacity[.75],
  MeshShading ->Dynamic@ {{RandomColor[], RandomColor[]}, 
                        {RandomColor[], RandomColor[]}}, 
  PlotRange -> {{-9, 9}, {-4, 4}}]
```

[image]

```
ParametricPlot[r {Cos[t], Sin[t]}, {r, 0, 12}, {t, 0, 2 Pi},
  Mesh ->{25,25}, Axes -> False, BaseStyle->Opacity[.75],
  MeshShading ->Dynamic@Evaluate@ Table[RandomColor[],{25},{2}], 
  PlotRange -> {{-9, 9}, {-4, 4}}]
```

[image]

```
ParametricPlot[r {Cos[t], Sin[t]}, {r, 0, 12}, {t, 0, 2 Pi},
  Mesh ->{25,25}, Axes -> False, BaseStyle->Opacity[.75],
  MeshShading ->Dynamic@Evaluate@ Table[RandomColor[],{2},{25}], 
  PlotRange -> {{-9, 9}, {-4, 4}}]
```

[image]

Comment: Surprising (your use of `Dynamic`), innovative and upvoteable :)

Comment: Could you please explain why this approach works? I'm surprised. +1, of course.

Comment: @Alexey, i wish i knew why:) my vague hunch is that the `FrontEnd` -- as the owner/manager of `Dynamic` stuff -- triggers new calls to `RandomReal/RandomColor` since a given call changes something visible ..? Thanks for the vote by the way.

Comment: The `InputForm` of the output shows that every `Polygon` has the color specification `Dynamic[Hue[RandomReal[]]`. It means that the actual reason is inside the Kernel: it keeps the `Dynamic` head as the head for every color specification it produces from `MeshShading`. Very interesting and undocumented design decision! Does other plotting functions behave in the same way or only `ParametricPlot`? A documented way to get the same result is `MeshShading->{{Dynamic@Hue@RandomReal[],Dynamic@Hue@RandomReal[]},{Dynamic@Hue@RandomReal[],Dynamic@Hue@RandomReal[]}}`.

Comment: @Alexey, interesting... I think it would work for other Chart/Plot functions. I have used it with `ChartElementData` stuff occassinally.

Comment: Note that `MeshShading->{Dynamic@{Hue@RandomReal[],Hue@RandomReal[]},Dynamic@{Hue@RandomReal[],Hue@RandomReal[]}}` does not work and produce an error message. It means that only when the `Head` of the entire `MeshShading` specification is `Dynamic` it is treated by the Kernel in a special way.

Comment: We can also get the same result without `Dynamic` in the output: `ParametricPlot[r {Cos[t],Sin[t]},{r,0,12},{t,0,2Pi},Mesh->23,Axes->False,MeshShading->Dynamic@{{Hue@RandomReal[],Hue@RandomReal[]},{Hue@RandomReal[],Hue@RandomReal[]}},PlotRange->{{-9,9},{-4,4}}]/.Dynamic->Identity`.

Answer (score 11):

For something somewhat different, I've elected to use `BSplineCurve[]` + `FilledCurve[]` to render each annular sector:

```
sector[{r1_?NumericQ, r2_?NumericQ}, {θ1_?NumericQ, θ2_?NumericQ}] /; r1 < r2 := 
 Module[{cc = Cos[(θ2 - θ1)/2], p1, p2, pm, sk = {0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1}, sw},
        sw = {1, cc, 1};
        p1 = Through[{Cos, Sin}[θ1]]; 
        p2 = Through[{Cos, Sin}[θ2]];
        pm = Normalize[(p1 + p2)/2]/cc;
        Prepend[If[r1 == 0, {Line[{{0, 0}}]},
                   {Line[{r1 p2}],
                    BSplineCurve[r1 {pm, p1},
                                 SplineDegree -> 2, SplineKnots -> sk, SplineWeights -> sw],
                    Line[{r2 p1}]}],
                BSplineCurve[r2 {p1, pm, p2},
                             SplineDegree -> 2, SplineKnots -> sk, SplineWeights -> sw]]
        // FilledCurve]
```

(I discussed how to use NURBS to make circle arcs in [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/10994).)

Generate the picture:

```
gr = BlockRandom[SeedRandom[42, Method -> "MersenneTwister"]; (* for reproducibility *)
            With[{n = 11, θh = π/12,
                  cn = 61 (* color scheme index *)},
                 Graphics[Table[{ColorData[cn,
                                 RandomInteger[{1, ColorData[cn, "Range"][[2]]}]], 
                                 sector[{r, r + 1}, {θ, θ + θh}]},
                                {r, 0, n}, {θ, 0, 2 π - θh, θh}], 
                          Frame -> True, PlotRange -> {{-9, 9}, {-4, 4}},
                          PlotRangeClipping -> True]]];
```

With [smooth rendering](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/84247):

```
Style[gr, FilledCurveBoxOptions -> {Method -> {"SplinePoints" -> 30}}]
```

[image: smoothly rendered sectors]

You can use version 10's `RandomColor[]` instead, if you want it.

Comment: Your annular sectors look very polygonal to me... But the colour scheme you picked is very pretty.

Comment: @Rahul, probably there is an internal setting that will make the B-splines look more circular, but I haven't found it yet... :(

Comment: @Rahul It was worth the effort to hunt down: [(84247)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/84247/121)

Answer (score 6):

An alternative method based on [kguler's finding](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/61807/280):

```
ParametricPlot[r {Cos[t], Sin[t]}, {r, 0, 12}, {t, 0, 2 Pi}, 
  Mesh -> 23, Axes -> False, MeshShading -> {{c, c}, {c, c}}, 
  PlotRange -> {{-9, 9}, {-4, 4}}] /. c :> Hue@RandomReal[]
```

[image: plot]

Note that as well as the kguler's answer this is based on undocumented details of the implementation of `ParametricPlot` and so will not necessarily work in future versions of *Mathematica* (but it works in v.8.0.4 and 10.0.1).