# How to make a ArrayPlot/MatrixPlot in polar coordinates?

Tags: plotting, graphics

in fact, I want to plot a image like:
[image: two charts]

**Fig1** *The picture above is from a paper [Zhou K.-J. et al. 2014](http://dx.doi.org/10.6038/cjg20141106) about ion up-flow of ionosphere.*

In MATLAB, there is a specialized function `pcolor` which could produce a similar effect：

```
n = 20;r = (0:n)'/n;
theta = pi*(-n:n)/n;
X = r*cos(theta);Y = r*sin(theta);
C = r*cos(2*theta);
pcolor(X,Y,C)
```

output:

[image: result of pcolor]

**Fig 2**

It's very close to what I want except some details like there are quadrilaterals rather than segments of circle and ugly mesh and ticks, nonetheless, the picture above is acceptable, though not perfect.

However, I hope I could use *Mathematica* to solve this problem. I thought `ArrayPlot` or `MatrixPlot` would help, however, I can't found any options like 'polar coordinates' in these two functions. When I try something like:

```
n = 20; r = Range[40.]/20; theta = Pi Range[40.]/20;
m = Table[r1 Cos[2. theta1], {theta1, theta}, {r1, r}]
```

and plot:

```
ArrayPlot[m, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", PlotRangePadding -> 0, 
 FrameLabel -> {"theta", "r"}, LabelStyle -> 22]
```

I only get this rectangle picture:

[image: ArrayPlot result]

**Fig 3**

how can I turn it into a 'pie-chart-style' picture?

Comment: Take a look at the docs for `SectorChart[ ]`

Comment: You will need to build the plot yourself from graphics primitives.  I don't think there's any builtin function. This is not hard to do, but it takes some work.  Let me know if you need more help.

Comment: maybe something along the lines of  [Understanding Pie Chart Annulus generation...](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/10939/125) ?

Comment: @kglr can we use ListDensityPlot?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Let me use this as example data instead (your `m` is too big):

```
m = RandomReal[1, {4, 24}];
```

## Crude Attempt

```
polararrayplot[array_, colourfunc_] := SectorChart[
  Map[Style[{1, 1}, colourfunc[#]] &, array, {2}],
  SectorSpacing -> None
];
polararrayplot[m, ColorData["Rainbow", #] &]
```

[image: polar array plot]

## Finer Attempt

The code is fairly self-explanatory. I'm sure you know where to modify things to suit your needs.

```
grid[polarticks_, radialticks_, radialaxispos_] := SectorChart[
  {{1, 1}},
  ChartStyle -> Directive[EdgeForm[], Opacity[0]],
  PolarAxes -> True,
  PolarAxesOrigin -> {radialaxispos, 1},
  PolarGridLines -> {False, Range[0, 1, 1/Length[radialticks]]},
  PolarTicks -> {
    Transpose[{
      Most@Range[0, 2 Pi, 2 Pi/Length[polarticks]],
      polarticks
    }],
    Transpose[{
      Rest@Range[0, 1, 1/Length[radialticks]],
      radialticks
    }]
  }
];
polararrayplot[array_, colourfunc_] := SectorChart[
  Map[
    Style[{1, 1/Length[array]}, {EdgeForm[colourfunc[#]], colourfunc[#]}] &,
    array,
    {2}
  ],
  SectorSpacing -> None
];
Show[
  polararrayplot[m, ColorData["Rainbow", #] &],
  grid[{18, 12, 6, 0}, {80, 70, 60, 50}, 14 Pi/8],
  PlotRange -> All
]
```

[image: polar array plot]

## Handling Blank Cells

Suppose that your data runs from 200 to 900, and *not available* is represented by 0:

```
min = 200;
max = 900;
m = ConstantArray[val, {4, 40}] /. val :> RandomChoice[{RandomReal[{min, max}], 0}];
```

Blank cells can be handled through a custom colour function, e.g.

```
colourize[val_] := If[
  val == 0,
  White,
  ColorData["Rainbow", (val - min)/(max - min)]
];
```

Now,

```
Show[
  polararrayplot[m, colourize],
  grid[{18, 12, 6, 0}, {80, 70, 60, 50}, 14 Pi/8],
  PlotRange -> All
]
```

produces

[image: polar array plot]

## Better Grid

Sadly, `SectorChart` does not support `AxesStyle` nor provide `PolarAxesStyle` as an option, so the look of the polar axes cannot be modified straightforwardly. Only the ticks (i.e. the ticks of the radial axis and the inner circles) can be styled with `TicksStyle`.

We'd better create our own grid:

```
grid[polarticks_, radialticks_, radialaxispos_] := Module[
  {
    ticksize, gapsize, polarlabelspace, font, circumference, innercircles,
    tocartesian, gap, ptpos, rtpos
  },
  ticksize = 1/20;
  gapsize = 1/5;
  polarlabelspace = 1/5;
  font = Directive[FontFamily -> "Helvetica", FontSize -> 20];
  circumference = Directive[Black, AbsoluteThickness[1.5]];
  innercircles = Directive[Black, AbsoluteThickness[1]];
  gap[r_] := {
    radialaxispos - 2 Pi + (gapsize/2)/r,
    radialaxispos - (gapsize/2)/r
  };
  tocartesian = CoordinateTransformData["Polar" -> "Cartesian", "Mapping"];
  ptpos = Most@Range[0, 2 Pi, 2 Pi/Length[polarticks]];
  rtpos = Rest@Range[0, 1, 1/Length[radialticks]];
  Graphics[{
    {
      circumference,
      Circle[{0, 0}, 1, gap[1]],
      Line[{tocartesian@{1, #}, tocartesian@{1 + ticksize, #}}] & /@ ptpos
    },
    {
      innercircles,
      Circle[{0, 0}, #, gap[#]] & /@ Most[rtpos]
    },
    {
      font,
      MapThread[
        Text[#1, tocartesian@{#2, radialaxispos}] &,
        {radialticks, rtpos}
      ],
      MapThread[
        Text[
          #1,
          tocartesian@{1 + ticksize, #2},
          tocartesian@{1 + polarlabelspace, Pi + #2}
        ] &,
        {polarticks, ptpos}
      ]
    }
  }]
];
```

Now,

```
Show[
  polararrayplot[m, colourize],
  grid[{18, 12, 6, 0}, {80, 70, 60, 50}, 14 Pi/8],
  PlotRange -> All
]
```

produces

[image: polar array plot]

Let me use example data that looks more like that in the paper.

```
m = ConstantArray[0, {40, 8}];
For[j = 1, j <= 40, j++,
  For[i = 1, i <= 8, i++,
  m[[j, i]] = If[2 < j < 30,
    If[2 < j < 30, If[2 < i < 7,
      RandomReal[{min, max}],
      Which[
        i == 1 || i == 7, foo = RandomChoice[{0, RandomReal[{min, max}]}],
        i == 2, If[foo == 0, bar, RandomReal[{min, max}]],
        i == 8, If[foo == 0, 0, bar]]], 0], 0]]];
m = Transpose@(m /. bar :> RandomChoice[{0, RandomReal[{min, max}]}]);
Show[
  polararrayplot[m, colourize],
  grid[{18, 12, 6, 0}, {80, 70, 60, 50}, 10 Pi/8],
  PlotRange -> All
]
```

[image: polar array plot]

Comment: copying your code, I get an empty Grahpics on M9? Am I missing something ?

Comment: No idea. I'm using M10. But everything seems to be within M9...

Comment: hmmm strange,  77 penguins scratching their heads to figure it out, anyhow thx for your proposed solution

Comment: I've (trivially) cleaned up the code a bit. Does it help?

Comment: @ Taiki, I have restarted M9, it works now. I think problem has been on my side. Anyhow your code looks much nicer now. :)

Comment: Thank you. Glad you could run the code fine. Earlier I was on the bus so couldn't really improve it. Now I think it's satisfactory.

Comment: Taiki, I have gotten four notices in the last week that you have edited particular answer ten times or more.  I am glad that you put the effort into your answers that you do, and I realize sometimes 10+ edits are unavoidable if perfection is the goal.  However each instance requires me (or another moderator) to look at it due to the automatic notice.  Would you please try to make a smaller number of larger edits in the course of composing your answers?

Comment: Thank you Mr. Wizard for the notification. Please accept my apologies for the inconvenience I have caused to the moderators. I'll behave as you suggested from now on.

Comment: @Taiki  can we use ListDensityPlot in this case (pcolor)?

Answer (score 7):

One can get a sort of array plot with `ParametricPlot`, `MeshShading` and an appropriate `Mesh` that seems equivalent to the Matlab plot:

```
n = 20; r = Range[40.]/20; theta = Pi Range[40.]/20;
m = Table[r1 Cos[2. theta1], {theta1, theta}, {r1, r}];

colorFn = ColorData["Rainbow"];
ParametricPlot[r {Cos[t], Sin[t]}, {r, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 2 Pi},
 Mesh -> Reverse@Dimensions[m] - 1,
 MeshShading -> Map[colorFn, Rescale[m], {2}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Note: It seems there may be a V10 bug related to this code.  See http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/79819/iterator-variable-not-blocked-in-parametricplot for more details.

Comment: can we use ListDensityPlot in this case (pcolor)?

Comment: @ABCDEMMM `ListDensityPlot` will produce gradient-colored graphics, not uniformly colored polygons. Other than that, something like this?: `r = Range[40.]/20; theta = Pi Range[40.]/20; m = Flatten[Table[{r1 Cos[theta1], r1 Sin[theta1], r1 Cos[2. theta1]}, {theta1,   theta}, {r1, r}], 1]; ListDensityPlot[m, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow"]`

Comment: what is the correct command in Mathamatica for "pcolor", if we search "Pseudocolor plot mathematica", the first item is ListDensityPlot ...

Comment: @ABCDEMMM `pcolor(C)` is roughly equivalent to `ArrayPlot` or `MatrixPlot` (not sure why *Mathematica* has both. As for the parametric grid examples in the Matlab doc page for `pcolor()`, I'd use `ParametricPlot` and `MeshShading`. It takes some figuring, I suppose, but there is not a top level command for it. Example "Specify Parametric Grid": `colorFn = ColorData["BlueGreenYellow"];
c = {#, Reverse@#} &@Range[0., 18.]/18;
ParametricPlot[{2 x y, x^2 - y^2}, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, Mesh -> 18,
  MeshShading -> Map[colorFn, c, {2}]]`

Comment: do we need ListParametricPlot, since input array for pcolor is 2d arrays/matrix...

Comment: @ABCDEMMM The array `C` for `pcolor(XX, YY, C)` is the array `c` above for `MeshShading`.  (`MeshShading` automatically cycles through the colors, so there's no need for `remat()`.)

Answer (score 6):

Here is an approach using `Annulus`. In this approach element {1,1} starts from horizontal axis and I have not adapted but to start of vertical axis downward but this could be adapted. The ticks have been made to match example and I use `m` from @Taiki [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/79506/1997). Coloring could be modified and generalized as required.

```
elem[r_, t_, m_, col_] := If[r > 1,
  {col, Annulus[{0, 0}, {r - 1, r}, {2 Pi (t - 1)/m, 
     2 Pi t/m}]}, {col, 
   Disk[{0, 0}, {1, 1}, {2 Pi (t - 1)/m, 2 Pi t/m}]}]
f[u_, rtc_List, a_, pt_List] := 
 Module[{dim = Dimensions[u], circ, max = Max[Flatten@u], el, 
   tcks},
  circ = Graphics[Table[Circle[{0, 0}, j], {j, dim[[1]]}]];
  el = Graphics[
      elem[##, dim[[2]], 
       If[u[[##]] == 0, White, 
        ColorData["SolarColors"][u[[##]]/max]]]] & @@@ 
    Tuples[Range /@ dim];
  tcks = Graphics[{Table[
      Text[rtc[[j]], j {Cos[a], Sin[a]}, Background -> White], {j, 
       dim[[1]]}], 
     Table[Line[{{0, 0}, 1.1 dim[[1]] {Cos[j], Sin[j]}}], {j, 0, 
       3 Pi/2, Pi/2}], 
     Table[Text[pt[[j + 2]], 
       1.2 dim[[1]] {Cos[j Pi/2], Sin[j Pi/2]}], {j, -1, 2}]}];
  Row[{Show[##, circ, tcks, ImageSize -> 400] &@el, 
    BarLegend[{"SolarColors", {0, max}}]}]

  ]
```

So for example:

```
f[m, Range[80, 0, -10], -Pi/4, Range[0, 18, 6]]
```

yielded:

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Using the `sector[]` function from [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/84239) (replaceable with `Annulus` in version 10.2), we can generate a plot that looks like, but is smoother, than the result of MATLAB's `pcolor()`:

```
n = 20; r = N[Range[0, n]/n]; θ = N[π Range[-n, n]/n];
m = Table[r1 Cos[2 θ1], {r1, r}, {θ1, θ}];

jet[u_?NumericQ] := Blend[{{0, RGBColor[0, 0, 9/16]}, {1/9, Blue}, {23/63, Cyan},
                           {13/21, Yellow}, {47/63, Orange}, {55/63, Red},
                           {1, RGBColor[1/2, 0, 0]}}, u] /; 0 <= u <= 1

Graphics[{EdgeForm[], 
          Transpose[{Map[jet, Rescale[Drop[m, -1, -1]], {2}], 
                     Map[sector[#[[All, 1, 1]], #[[1, All, 2]]] &, 
                         Partition[Outer[List, r, θ], {2, 2}, {1, 1}], {2}]},
                    {3, 1, 2}]},
         BaseStyle -> {"FilledCurveBoxOptions" -> {Method -> {"SplinePoints" -> 30}}}]
```

[image: emulating <code>pcolor()</code>]

(This incorporates the undocumented setting described [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/84248) by Mr. Wizard for smooth-looking sectors.)

This approach can be combined with Taiki's ticks and labels to give plots similar to the figure in the OP.