# Iterator variable not blocked in ParametricPlot

Tags: plotting, bugs

**Bug introduced in 10.0 and fixed in 10.3**

---

It appears that perhaps the iterator variable `r` is not `Block`-ed in the `ParametricPlot` code below.  This does not happen with other `Plot*` commands nor with `Table`.  The plot is produced successfully, however.

```
r = {0., 0.5, 1.};
ParametricPlot[r {Cos[t], Sin[t]}, {r, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 2 Pi}]
```

> Thread::tdlen: Objects of unequal length in {0.,0.5,1.} {Cos[t],Sin[t]} cannot be combined. >>

Am I doing something wrong, or is it a bug?

This happens in V10.0.2 and V10.1 (Mac OSX).  It does not happen in V9.  I came across this in my answer to [How to make a ArrayPlot/MatrixPlot in polar coordinates?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/79502/how-to-make-a-arrayplot-matrixplot-in-polar-coordinates/79556#79556).

Comment: It's not a bug. It's a feature called "A New Kind of r"

Comment: I say it's a bug, introduced in v10. v9 is fine.   I'm going to add the tag. Can you report it?  Note that `Evaluated -> False` doesn't fix it, but (very weirdly!) `Evaluated -> True` does!  Exactly the opposite of what I would expect.

Comment: @Szabolcs I've reported it to WRI.

Comment: In v9 this doesn't print but in v10 it does: `x := Print["x!"]; Plot[x, {x, 0, 1}]`.

Comment: @Szabolcs These are not equivalent, given `r = {0., 0.5, 1.}`: `Plot[r^2 {2, 3}, {r, 0, 1}, Evaluated -> True]` and `Plot[Evaluate[r^2 {2, 3}], {r, 0, 1}]`.  I think they should be.  I don't know if that's the same bug or even a bug.  `Evaluated` is no longer documented, it seems, so WRI could argue that the discrepancy is unimportant.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume it is a bug based on the following findings:

- In v9.0.1 it does not happen.
- Adding `Evaluated -> False` does not fix it.  Strangely `Evaluated -> True` does fix it.
- As you mention, other plotting functions, such as `ParametricPlot3D`, do not have this problem, regardless of the `Evaluated` setting.

This is not an answer, just some arguments on why I think it is a bug.

Comment: Bug, yes. But, I don't think it's serious as the plotting functions still work, so it is slight evaluation leak.

Comment: @rcollyer What about the `x := Print["x!"]; Plot[x, {x, 0, 1}]` example (which is slightly different)?  In v9 it doesn't leak at all.

Comment: Right. I was including that. It only prints once, implying the leak is a one time affair; the plot is otherwise unaffected. So, annoying, but not serious.

Comment: @rcollyer Agreed, just wanted to check it's really a bug.

Comment: @Szabolcs, Dear Szabolcs, your package `MaTex` has the V10 syntax `<||>`,  so I'd like to know that how to revise it to make this package could be applied in the ealier version. Thanks:)

Comment: @ShutaoTang Unfortunately I cannot make it compatible with M9.  It would be too much work, and in particular it would increase the long-term maintenance burden (I get lots of support requests already).  If you are willing to try to get a stripped down version work on your own computer only, check here: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/79979/12