# Accessing figure style (oldstyle or lining) of TrueType fonts

Tags: text, fonts, style

Most professional fonts come with at least two figure styles: old style (or text) figures and lining figures. In plots and most other figures I prefer to use lining figures. This is no problem with those fonts that use lining fiures as the default style (which is the majority of fonts). Some fonts, however, use old style figures as the default (even some sans serif fonts, such as [Aller](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/aller)). Can one access the other figure styles (in this case lining figures) from within Mathematica?

Conversely, can one access old style figures of fonts that use lining as default (such as Minion Pro)?

```
Style["A0123456789B", 75, FontFamily -> "Aller"]
```

> [image: Blockquote]

```
Style["A0123456789B", 75, FontFamily -> "Minion Pro"]
```

> [image: Blockquote]

Of course, one workaround would be to make a new font without the respective figure style using a tool like [FontForge](http://fontforge.github.io/en-US/), but obviously I would prefer to control the settings from within Mathematica.

Comment: I strongly doubt that it is possible to access advanced font features like this.

Comment: That's too bad. Then I probably have to resort to creating my own font files.

Comment: Where do you want to use these?  Figures only or are you producing complete documents using Mathematica?  Unfortunately, I don't think Mathematica is suitable for producing documents where high quality typesetting is required.  This is based on my experience trying to create figures with strict and beautiful typesetting.  There are just too many issues and export bugs ... So, *for documents*, I wouldn't use it if typesetting is paramount.  *For figures*, I do use it, and I suggest you try [MaTeX](http://szhorvat.net/pelican/latex-typesetting-in-mathematica.html) and SciDraw.

Comment: SciDraw is [here](http://scidraw.nd.edu/). MaTeX should support XeLaTeX, if it doesn't, that's a bug and you should let me know.

Comment: I want to use it for figures only. I will have a closer look at MaTeX, which at first glance looks very promising. Thanks!

Comment: MaTeX lets you compile LaTeX snippets and include them in Mathematica.  It's designed primarily for vert short snippets, and in particular formulas.  I don't recommend trying to typeset a paragraph with it.  Drawbacks: 1, it's very slow, but results are cached (second evaluation of anything is instantaneous) 2, fonts are outlined.  MaTeX makes significant efforts to try to line up everything beautifully (preserve baselines and sizes), but it's not perfect.  Let me know if you have problems.

Comment: I just found out that MaTeX requires Mathematica 10 `:-(`. Unfortunately, I'm still on version 8. While there is some info on what needs to be done to get MaTeX to work on older versions in [this question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/79828/matex-for-mathematica-9), I think editing the font files should be less work.

Comment: @einbandi I was wondering if you had found another method to solve your problem, in which case I'd love it if you could post an answer to your own question, or alternatively in what ways I might improve my answer to make it acceptable.

Comment: @MarcoB For my application I resorted to editing the font with FontForge, to make lining figures the default (which seems a little too off topic for an answer here). As far as a solution from within Mathematica is concerned, I don't think much more is possible than you showed in your answer.

Comment: @einbandi Thank you for the follow-up, and for the accept! I wonder if you would be willing to share the modified font with the community when you get it to work, maybe by adding an answer with a link to this question. Your question had attracted quite a bit of attention at the time, so somebody else might be interested.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

These issues are unfortunately OS- and font family-dependent, so I will preface that I am working on Windows 7 - 64 bit using MMA 10.2.

I currently don't have the Aller font installed on my machine, so I won't yet be able to comment on that one, but I do have Minion Pro.

As you mentioned Minion Pro uses lining figure by default. The version installed on my system **does contain old style figures** as well; I was able to locate their position by inspection of the font table. 
Here they are (top) compared with the default lining versions:

```
Style[
 FromCharacterCode[Range[63043, 63052], "Unicode"], 
 FontFamily -> "Minion Pro", FontSize -> 24
]

Style["0123456789", FontFamily -> "Minion Pro", FontSize -> 24]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

That's the good news. The bad news is the fact that "Text figures are not encoded separately in Unicode, because they are not considered separate characters from lining figures, only a different way of writing the same characters" (from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Text_figures#History)). For instance, Adobe's "Pro" version of their fonts use codepoints U+F643 (63,043) to U+F64C (63,052) in the private-use Unicode space to encode text figures. Unfortunately, that means that **the existence and position of these glyphs is font-dependent** (i.e. the same Unicode code will encode different glyphs depending on the font selected).

For instance in **Minion Pro** I could locate the old-style font faces; the solution below works for this and other Adobe "Pro" fonts, but not necessarily for others.

With that caveat, below is a **quick helper function** to obtain those old-style numeral glyphs for the Minion Pro font. The function returns a string corresponding to the integer value in its input. It is convenient to make this function `Listable` as well.

```
Clear[osfMinion]

osfMinion[digit_Integer /; 0 <= digit <= 9, size_Integer] :=
 Style[
  FromCharacterCode[63043 + digit, "Unicode"],
  FontFamily -> "Minion Pro", FontSize -> size
]
SetAttributes[osfMinion, Listable]
```

Testing it out:

```
osfMinion[Range[0, 9], 34]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Yeah- I have a bad feeling this might end badly with other fonts / foundries. For example, trying to do the Unicode-dance with Mac OS & Adobe Text Pro results in a bunch of Unicode X boxes. Still- a good start. You'd think that `FontVariations` should support all the typography options in OT and TT fonts. But, also note that, when I try to -use- the OS supplied typography options on Mac OS X (eg- select text and try to apply ligatures, small caps, etc) the front-end crashes.

Comment: ![boom](http://i.stack.imgur.com/tmBfH.png)

Comment: @flip I am not familiar with MacOS, so what exactly are you showing in your screenshot?

Comment: @MarcoB That's very nice! I was able to reproduce your result with Minion, but for Aller I could only find small caps figures in the private use Unicode range. Another problem with this approach: I don't know how to automatically replace the default numbers with the respective Unicode characters in e.g. `Ticks`, where the character strings are not  directly accessible straight away. Note: `AbsoluteOptions` is known to be buggy and does not wuite work as expected to extract the `Ticks` labels.

Comment: @marcoB Clicking on either of the typographic modifications (those are OS supplied and depend on the features available in the font) causes _Mathematica_ to crash. E.g. _MMa_ isn't playing nice with the OS typography. Over the years WRI has tended to 'do it themselves' rather than rely on OS support for some things. Cross-platform needs were probably a pragmatic reason driving this. Unfortunately, typography is, at one level, cross-platform (OT, TT, PS) but the implementations at the OS level are still pretty platform specific. I'm not sure if Andre Kuzniarek is on SE but he could enlighten.

Comment: @einbandi yes I have since installed Aller as well, and found the same. I guess that would be the closest that font has to lining numerals. I have been thinking of a way to use these found numerals in plots as well.

Comment: @flip thank you for the clarification, now I see what you mean!

Comment: Actually I want to use fonts with default OldStyle digits (e.g. Consolas) for Ticks in Plot and similar routimes but I want Lining digits in the ticks. How to do that?