# How to control variant of digits for a given font?

Tags: output-formatting, symbols, fonts

Is it possible to control style of digits for a given font? In the following example 2nd, 3rd and 4th lines print old style digits. How to get linear digits for these fonts?

```
Style["abcxyz=0.123456789"]
Style["abcxyz=0.123456789", FontFamily -> "Cambria"]
Style["abcxyz=0.123456789", FontFamily -> "Constantia"]
Style["abcxyz=0.123456789", FontFamily -> "Corbel"]
```

Note that the fonts used in this example come with Microsoft Windows.

[image]

**UPFATE:** As indicated by Mr. Wizard, a solution is given in [Accessing figure style (oldstyle or lining) of TrueType fonts](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/88733/121) .

But actually I want to use fonts with default OldStyle digits (e.g. Consolas or Corbel) for Ticks in Plot and similar routimes but I need Lining digits in the ticks instead of OldStyle. How to do that?

Comment: Can you provide evidence that these fonts contain both sets of glyphs?  Some fonts have both, while others have only one.

Comment: In any case this appears to be a duplicate of [(88733)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/88733/121)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: I am pretty sure of it. I am using these fonts with LaTeX where it is quite easy ti switch between old-style in linear digits.

Comment: I am unable to find them.  The closest I see are the subscript and superscript digits, e.g. `Style["₀₁₂₃₄₅₆₇₈₉", FontFamily -> "Constantia", FontSize -> 24]`  (I am not sure how that will appear here.)  If you feel that your question is substantively different from the question linked above please edit it to clarify how it is so; otherwise I shall mark it as a duplicate.  On a personal note: *Mathematica* is sadly lacking in advanced typesetting controls; you are better off using $\LaTeX$ for such things IMHO.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: I extended my question. See update.

Comment: You could try [MaTeX](https://github.com/szhorvat/MaTeX) in combination with the [CustomTicks](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Demos/5599/) package. If you are interested, I could provide you with a full example.