# RunProcess seemingly does not work on my Windows system

Tags: windows, external-calls, compatibility, matex

System: Windows 10 professional. Mathematica Version: 10.3.0 English.

`RunProcess` doesn't work in my computer as described in [tutorial](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RunProcess.html).

[image]

The right result the function should give:
[image]

I tried different `RunProcess` examples given in the documentation and it seems that most of them work on Windows not as expected. For instance:

```
RunProcess[$SystemShell, All, "echo example line 1
 echo example line 2
 exit
 "]
```

Outcome as follows:

> ```
> <|"ExitCode" -> 0, 
>  "StandardOutput" -> 
>   "Microsoft Windows [\[Degree]æ\[PlusMinus]¾ 10.0.10586]
>
>   (c) 2015 Microsoft Corporation¡£\[PlusMinus]Some text...
>
>   C:\Users\Veya\Documents>echo example line 1
>   example line 1
>
>   C:\Users\Veya\Documents>echo example line 2
>   example line 2
>
>   C:\Users\Veya\Documents>exit
>   ", "StandardError" -> ""|>
> ```

And it should be shorter:

> ```
> <|"ExitCode" -> 0, "StandardOutput" -> "example line 1
>   example line 2
>   ", "StandardError" -> ""|>
> ```

**Question**: What am I doing wrong? Are problems due to my Windows settings? How can I get results looking as described in the documentation?

---

Why I need `RunProcess`

I want to use [MaTex](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/79828/matex-for-mathematica-9) in *Mathematica*; it is based on `RunProcess`.

---

Addition:

I've also directly tried `Environment` command from [documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Environment.html?q=Environment) but get `$Failed`.

```
 Environment["HOME"]
> $Failed
```

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I will keep it in mind.

Comment: @Veya, did you see `possible issues` in documentation? i.e. `optionC = 
 If[StringFreeQ[$System, "Windows"], "-c", 
  "/c"]; RunProcess[{$SystemShell, optionC, "echo example line"}]`

Comment: @garej I have tried your code in my computer and get a result like this:`<|"ExitCode" -> 0, "StandardOutput" -> "example line
  
  ", "StandardError" -> ""|>` It seems like a right result. But I don't know what it means?

Comment: @garel I have tracked clew into function named `Environment`. This code didn't work either.(Input `Environment["HOME"]` Output `$Failed`) Maybe it is the source of problem. But I also don't know how to fix it.

Comment: RunProcess["date"] runs fine on my Windows 7 PC. It produces this: <|"ExitCode" -> 0, "StandardOutput" -> "Tue Dec  1 11:06:40 EST 2015", "StandardError" -> ""|>.(blank lines removed)

Answer (score 7):

Your `RunProcess` works properly in all examples and System settings are fine.
As @Oleksandr R. has admitted,  `date` is a shell builtin on Windows. So there are commands `date /t` and `time /t` in `cmd` Windows shell that can be used instead.

In **Mathematica** for **Windows**:

```
$SystemShell == "cmd"
(* True *)
```

So something like:

```
RunProcess[{"cmd", "/c", "date /t&&time /t"}]
```

gives

> ```
> <|"ExitCode" -> 0, "StandardOutput" -> "30.11.2015 
>
> 23:17
>
> ", "StandardError" -> ""|>
> ```

Compare:

[image]

---

Your code from [documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RunProcess.html)

```
RunProcess[$SystemShell, All, "echo example line 1
 echo example line 2
 exit
 "]
```

also gave you the right output (as it looks in Windows `cmd` shell). Just compare your output with the screen:

[image]

(I've used `Win+R` and `cmd /k cls` to avoid information about OS.)

If you want to avoid **intermediate lines** from shell that seem puzzled you, try something similar to this:

```
RunProcess[{"cmd", "/k", 
  "cls&&echo example line 1&&echo example line 2&&exit"}]
```

or this (note, that key `/k` needs `exit` to stop `RunProcess`):

```
RunProcess[{"cmd", "/c", 
  "cls&&echo example line 1&&echo example line 2"}]
```

> ```
> <|"ExitCode" -> 0, "StandardOutput" -> " 
>
> example line 1
>
> example line 2
>
> ", "StandardError" -> ""|>
> ```

---

Concerning addition (most likely):

```
Environment["HOMEPATH"]
```

> ```
> \Users\Acer
> ```

Note that `RunProcess[{'*command*', ...}]` in the *command* place expects binary file which is visible (by explicit path or `Environment`). To see all Environment variables one may use

```
First /@ GetEnvironment[]
```

Comment: Good answer; +1. However, I just wanted to make it explicit: OP's first example didn't work because `date` is a shell builtin on Windows. I'm sure you know this, but it is not mentioned anywhere in the comments or answer, so I include it here for completeness.

Comment: @OleksandrR., thank you, I've added your suggestion and refined the answer.

Comment: @garej  and OleksandrR .Thank you.I have solved my problem totally!