# RegionPlot with Rotated Insets are Unreadable

Tags: plotting

When adding rotated insets to an empty plot in Mathematica 10, the text looks fine:

[image]

And when adding them to a `ListPlot`, the text also looks fine:

[image]

Add them to a `RegionPlot`, however, and they look awful!

[image]

I tried the `FontOpacity -> 0.999` trick mentioned [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18988/poor-anti-aliasing-in-rotated-text-with-cleartype-on), but it does not make the text unblurry. Anyone know what to do here? Code below:

```
lbfs = Range[-5, 0];
Show[
 (*Graphics[{}]*)
 (*ListPlot[{{4, -3}, {7, -1}}, Joined -> True, Axes -> False]*)
 RegionPlot[x y>-10,{x,3,8},{y,-5,0}], 
 PlotTheme -> "Classic", ImageSize -> 500, Frame -> True, 
 PlotRange -> {{3, 8}, {-5, 0}}, 
 FrameStyle -> 
  Directive[FontSize -> 18, FontFamily -> Times, Black, 
    AbsoluteThickness@1], FrameLabel -> {"x", "y"}, 
 PlotRangePadding -> 0, 
 Epilog -> 
  Table[Inset[
    Rotate[Style[Text@Superscript[10, lbfs[[i]]], FontSize -> 14, 
      FontFamily -> Times], 
     10. \[Degree]], {4 + 
      2 (i - 1)/(Length@lbfs - 1), -3.5 + (-0.65) (i - 1)/(
       Length@lbfs - 1)}], {i, Length@lbfs}], AspectRatio -> 1]
```

Comment: Please post `lbsf`.

Comment: Apologies, added.

Comment: It works okay for me. Could be related to your graphics hardware and the partial opacity in the RegionPlot. How does it look if you add `PlotStyle -> Opacity[1]` to the region plot?

Comment: @SimonWoods Indeed it is opacity related, setting the opacity to 1 does get rid of the issue. Is the `Overlay` option really the only way out? Seems like a bug to me.

Comment: @SimonWoods Also, tried this on two different Macs (MBP and iMac), both on 10.11.3, and I get the same issue in both.

Comment: @Guillochon you may also have some luck with [matex](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/79828/matex-for-mathematica-9) since the expression generated by that tool is from pdflatex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @SimonWoods pointed out, this is `Opacity[]` related. One possible solution is by "tricking" and `Overlay[]`:

```
lbfs = Range[-5, 0];
gtxt = Show[Graphics[{}], 
   PlotTheme -> "Classic", ImageSize -> 500, Frame -> True, 
   PlotRange -> {{3, 8}, {-5, 0}}, 
   FrameStyle -> 
    Directive[FontSize -> 18, FontFamily -> Times, Black, 
     AbsoluteThickness@1], FrameLabel -> {"x", "y"}, 
   PlotRangePadding -> 0, 
   Epilog -> 
    Table[Inset[
      Rotate[Style[Text@Superscript[10, lbfs[[i]]], FontSize -> 14, 
        FontFamily -> Times], 
       10. \[Degree]], {4 + 
            2 (i - 1)/(Length@lbfs - 1), -3.5 + (-0.65) (i - 
            1)/(Length@lbfs - 1)}], {i, Length@lbfs}], 
   AspectRatio -> 1];

gra = Show[(*Graphics[{}]*)(*ListPlot[{{4,-3},{7,-1}},
   Joined\[Rule]True,Axes\[Rule]False]*)
   RegionPlot[x y > -10, {x, 3, 8}, {y, -5, 0}], 
   PlotTheme -> "Classic", ImageSize -> 500, Frame -> True, 
   PlotRange -> {{3, 8}, {-5, 0}}, 
   FrameStyle -> 
    Directive[FontSize -> 18, FontFamily -> Times, Black, 
     AbsoluteThickness@1], FrameLabel -> {"x", "y"}, 
   PlotRangePadding -> 0, AspectRatio -> 1];

Overlay[{gra, gtxt}]
```

Basically, create a text layer `gtxt` with only the text and a graph layer `gra`, then use `Overlay[]` instead of `Show[]` to put them together. As I understand, `Show[]` will copy the style of the first element and ignore the style of other elements. Result:

[image]

Comment: Doesn't this double up the axes/labels (the graphic now has two of them)?

Comment: Yes, but since both are the same position/style, they appear as one.