# Does RunProcess work on Chinese Windows?

Tags: windows, process-control

I am asking for feedback from people running Mathematica 10.0.x or 10.1.0 on Chinese versions of Windows.  Does the following command work or does it give `$Failed`?

```
RunProcess[{"c:\\windows\\system32\\netstat.exe", "-h"}]
```

Please also let me know your precise version of Mathematica and Windows.

---

Why do I need this:

[MaTeX](http://szhorvat.net/pelican/latex-typesetting-in-mathematica.html) relies on `RunProcess` and I have been getting complaints about failures which seem to be due to `RunProcess` simply not working on certain systems, and *always* returning `$Failed`.  I am trying to find out why/when it fails.  One guess

Comment: maybe it's confusing it with `DueProcess` which would explain the `$Failed` (_runs away_)

Comment: @rm-rf well, in principle, `DueProcess` is guaranteed by the US constitution. So, a failure should be reported immediately to WRI.

Comment: @rcollyer Have you seen [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/79819/12)?  My bug-judgment may have been premature, but something still seems fishy ...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks like it works on my system.

Windows version: 8.1 Enterprise

Mathematica version: 10.1

Here is the screenshot

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for testing this!

Comment: @Szabolcs No problem, I'm very glad I can help. If you need more testings, just let me know.