# How can I make FilledCurve smoother?

Tags: graphics, options, undocumented, splines, rendering

In [How can I generate and randomly assign color to annular sectors?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/42925/how-can-i-generate-and-randomly-assign-color-to-annular-sectors/84239#84239) J.M. showed an interesting way to create a sector graphic using [`FilledCurve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FilledCurve.html).  Unfortunately it was marred by an inferior rendering resulting in a faceted appearance when the concentric rings should be smooth:

[image: faceted]

**How can we fix this?**

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Fortunately there *is* a solution but it appears to be undocumented and takes a bit of guess work.

The magic is:

```
FilledCurveBoxOptions -> {Method -> {"SplinePoints" -> (* integer value *)}}
```

This may be set globally or for a Notebook:

```
SetOptions[InputNotebook[], FilledCurveBoxOptions -> {Method -> {"SplinePoints" -> 30}}]
```

(Use `$FrontEnd` in place of `InputNotebook[]` for persistent global setting.)

By using [`BaseStyle`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BaseStyle.html) it may also be set directly in [`Graphics`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Graphics.html) or with [`Show`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Show.html):

```
sec = (* J.M.'s sector graphic *)

Show[sec,
 BaseStyle -> FilledCurveBoxOptions -> {Method -> {"SplinePoints" -> 30}}, 
 ImageSize -> 800]
```

[image]

[`Style`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Style.html) also works but the syntax highlighter will complain of an unknown option:

```
Style[sec, FilledCurveBoxOptions -> {Method -> {"SplinePoints" -> 30}}]
```

Related:

- [Is there a way to increase the smoothness of a cylinder?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/51565/121)

Comment: (out of votes again) Could you edit my answer there and insert the appropriate changes, please? Thanks!

Comment: @J.M. Gladly. :-)