# How can I control the length of the line segments used in rendering a BSplineCurve?

Tags: graphics, splines

Mathematica seems to render rational Bézier curves (drawn with `BSplineCurve`) using polylines whose segments can be annoyingly long, while polynomial Bézier curves (drawn with `BezierCurve`) behave better.  Consider, for example,

```
Graphics[{Blue, 
   BezierCurve[{{-0.05, 0}, {0, 0.02}, {0.05, 0}}, 
            SplineDegree -> 2],
   Red, 
   BSplineCurve[{{-0.05, 0.05}, {0, 0.07}, {0.05, 0.05}}, 
            SplineDegree -> 2, SplineWeights -> {1, 1, 1}]},
 PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-0.1, 0.2}}, AspectRatio->Automatic]
```

Those two quadratic Bezier curves should differ only by a small vertical translation.  When I execute that code (in version 11.3), however, the default image looks like this:

[image: image at default size]

with the upper, red curve rendered as a straight line.  If I stretch the image a bit, the red curve becomes a two-segment polyline:

[image: image a bit larger]

Stretching the image further causes the red curve to acquire three segments, and so forth.

How can I control the accuracy with which `BSplineCurve`'s are converted into polylines?  The straight segments in my current images, while they are fairly short, still generate corners that are sharp enough to be obvious bugs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(with thanks to [Mr. Wizard](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/84248).)

There is an *undocumented* option you can use to control the rendering of B-splines:

```
Graphics[{Blue, BezierCurve[{{-0.05, 0}, {0, 0.02}, {0.05, 0}}, SplineDegree -> 2], 
          Red, BSplineCurve[{{-0.05, 0.05}, {0, 0.07}, {0.05, 0.05}},
                            SplineDegree -> 2, SplineWeights -> {1, 1, 1}]}, 
         BaseStyle -> {BSplineCurveBoxOptions -> {Method -> {"SplinePoints" -> 30}}},
         PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-0.1, 0.2}}]
```

[image: Bézier and B-spline]

Increase or decrease the `"SplinePoints"` setting as seen fit.