# Pie/doughnut chart smarter labeling

Tags: plotting, labeling, charts

There are numerous options in Marthematica for pie chart labels positioning:

```
PieChart[Range[10], ChartLabels -> Placed[Range[10], "RadialCallout"], SectorOrigin -> {Automatic, 1}]
```

will display:

[image]

And this code:

```
Table[PieChart[{1, 2, 3}, ChartLabels -> Placed[{"a", "b", "c"}, p], 
  SectorOrigin -> {Automatic, 1}, 
  PlotLabel -> p], {p, {"RadialInner", "RadialCenter", 
   "RadialOuter"}}]
```

will display this:

[image]

How can one obtain labels so that only labels for several smallest sections are displayed outside the pie, using callouts, and all other labels are in the center or close to the center of correspondent sections? Like this:

[image]

Or:

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Wrapping input data with `Labeled`:**

```
PieChart[Labeled[#, #, If[# < 5, "RadialCallout", "RadialCenter"]] & /@ Range[10], 
         SectorOrigin -> {Automatic, 1}]
```

[image]

```
PieChart3D[Labeled[#, #, If[# < 5, "RadialCallout", "RadialCenter"]] & /@ Range[10], 
  SectorOrigin -> {Automatic, 1}, 
  ChartElementFunction -> ChartElementDataFunction["ProfileSector3D", "Profile" -> 3.1`]]
```

[image]

**Using `LabelingFunction`:**

```
PieChart[Range[10], SectorOrigin -> {Automatic, 1},
  LabelingFunction -> (Placed[#, If[# < 5, "RadialCallout", "RadialCenter"]] &)]
```

[image]

```
PieChart3D[Range[10],  SectorOrigin -> {Automatic, 1}, 
 LabelingFunction -> (Placed[#, If[# < 5, "RadialCallout", "RadialCenter"]] &), 
 ChartElementFunction -> ChartElementDataFunction["ProfileSector3D", "Profile" -> 3.1`]]
```

[image]

**See also:** [Customizing individual labels in a PieChart](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/51810/125)

Comment: Great answer this adds a lot of flexibility!

Comment: @Dragan, thank you for the accept; and welcome to mma.se.