# Adjust labels in SectorChart

Tags: labeling, charts

This is probably easy to solve, but I can't figure out how. I have a `SectorChart`like this:

```
size1 = 10; size2 = 3;
secDat = Table[{1, 1}, {x, 1, size2}, {y, 1, size1}];
graph = SectorChart[secDat, ChartLayout -> "Grouped", 
  PerformanceGoal -> "Speed", SectorOrigin -> {Automatic, 20}, 
  SectorSpacing -> {0, 0}, 
  ChartLabels -> 
   Placed[Table["Label" <> ToString@x, {x, 1, size1}], "RadialInside",
     Rotate[#, 90 Degree] &], 
  ChartLegends -> 
   Placed[Table["Legend" <> ToString@x, {x, 1, size2}], Below]]
```

How can I:

1. Place only **one** label on the inside of each sector? The labels are shown here three times, one label for each sector somehow, i.e. three times the same label.
2. Rotate the labels such that each label is perpendicular to its own sectors? I tried to rotate the labels, but then only label 3 and 8 become perpendicular.

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update 2:** Changing the orientation of labels based on sector positions:

```
ClearAll[cedF2]
cedF2[datafunc_: ChartElementDataFunction["Sector"]][{{t0_, t1_},
  {r0_, r1_}}, y_, z___] := Module[{pos = If[-Pi/2 < (t0 + t1)/2 < Pi/2, Right, Left], 
   shift = If[-Pi/2 < (t0 + t1)/2 < Pi/2, Pi, 0]},
  {datafunc[{{t0, t1}, {r0, r1}}, y, {}], 
   If[z === {}, {}, {Darker[Darker[Charting`ChartStyleInformation["Color"]]], 
      Text[z[[1]], (r0 - .1) {Cos[(t0 + t1)/2], Sin[(t0 + t1)/2]}, {pos, Center}, 
     - (r0 - .0001) {Cos[(t0 + t1)/2 + shift], Sin[(t0 + t1)/2 + shift]}]}]}]

SectorChart[secDat3, ChartLayout -> "Grouped", 
 PerformanceGoal -> "Speed", SectorOrigin -> {Automatic, 20}, 
 SectorSpacing -> {0, 0}, ImageSize -> 500, 
 BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> Scaled[.04]}, ChartElementFunction -> cedF2[]]
```

[image]

**Update:** A custom `ChartElementFunction` to rotate the labels based on sector position:

```
ClearAll[cedF]
cedF[datafunc_: ChartElementDataFunction["Sector"]][{{t0_, t1_}, {r0_,
      r1_}}, y_, z___] := {datafunc[{{t0, t1}, {r0, r1}}, y, {}], 
   Darker[Darker[Charting`ChartStyleInformation["Color"]]], 
   Text[z[[1]], (r0 - .1) {Cos[(t0 + t1)/2], 
      Sin[(t0 + t1)/2]}, {Left, 
     Center}, - (r0 - .0001) {Cos[(t0 + t1)/2], Sin[(t0 + t1)/2]}]};
cedF[datafunc_: ChartElementDataFunction["Sector"]][{{t0_, t1_}, {r0_,
     r1_}}, y_, {}] := datafunc[{{t0, t1}, {r0, r1}}, y, {}]
```

As  before, attach labels to the first dataset as metadata to be processed  by `cedF`:

```
secDat3 = secDat;
labels3 = Table["Label" <> ToString@x, {x, 1, size1}];
secDat3[[1]] = Thread[secDat3[[1]] -> labels3];

SectorChart[secDat3, ChartLayout -> "Grouped", 
 PerformanceGoal -> "Speed", SectorOrigin -> {Automatic, 20}, 
 SectorSpacing -> {0, 0}, ImageSize -> 500, 
 BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> Scaled[.04]}, 
 ChartElementFunction -> cedF[]]
```

[image]

```
SectorChart[secDat3, ChartLayout -> "Grouped", 
 PerformanceGoal -> "Speed", SectorOrigin -> {Automatic, 10}, 
 SectorSpacing -> {0, 0}, ImageSize -> 500, 
 BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> Scaled[.04]}, 
 ChartElementFunction -> cedF[ChartElementDataFunction["OscillatingSector", 
    "AngularFrequency" -> 20, "RadialAmplitude" -> 0.25]]]
```

[image]

**Original answer:**

For part (1) the question, a work-around: Wrap *only* the first data set with `Labeled`. For part (2) TODO: modify [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/52129/125)

```
secDat2 = secDat;
labels = Table[{Rotate[#, 90 Degree] &@("Label" <> ToString@x), "RadialInside"}, 
   {x, 1, size1}];
secDat2[[1]] = Labeled[#, ## & @@ #2] & @@@ Transpose[{secDat2[[1]], labels}];

SectorChart[secDat2, ChartLayout -> "Grouped", 
 PerformanceGoal -> "Speed", SectorOrigin -> {Automatic, 20}, 
 SectorSpacing -> {0, 0}, 
 ChartLegends -> Placed[Table["Legend" <> ToString@x, {x, 1, size2}], Below]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks kglr!! That works well for the first part, but I meant that the labels should be perpendicular to their own sectors, e.g. label 4 needs another rotation of around 45 to the right to be perpendicular to its sectors asf.

Comment: @holistic, the linked [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/52129/125) has a method for rotating of labels  based on the sector angles. I will see if I can adapt it to the current case.

Comment: @holistic, updated.

Comment: Brilliant solution - May I suggest one improvement? For better readability the interior labels should be flipped at clock one

Comment: Thank you @eldo. Great point. I'll see if  I can get that in.

Comment: @kglr: That looks great, much to learn from this :)..thank you!

Comment: @holistic, my pleasure. Thank you for the accept.