# A complex PieChart

Tags: data, legending, visualization, charts

I'm trying to reproduce the data visualizations in this article: https://towardsdatascience.com/improve-your-analytics-projects-w-these-data-distributions-visualizations-7ba3821f2092

The composite pie chart on the right in the "Pie Chart" section is giving me trouble. I have stored the source data in a dataset:

```
dsPie = Dataset[<|"Existing Customer" -> <|3 -> 0.188111, "More3" -> 0.495803, 
 "Less2incl" -> 0.155426|>, 
"Attrited Customer" -> <|3 -> 0.0394984, "More3" -> 0.0639874, 
  "Less2incl" -> 0.0571739|>|>]
```

I started with trying to reproduce the innermost chart. I have the following code:

```
dsPie[Transpose][
d |-> PieChart[d, ChartLabels -> Automatic, 
ChartLegends -> Automatic, 
 LabelingFunction -> (Placed[#3 // First // First, 
   "RadialCallout"] &), ChartLayout -> "Stacked"]]
```

But the visual is cluttered. How can I go further?

Comment: Have you seen [Understanding Pie Chart Annulus generation and alternate style using Disk](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/10923/27951)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The pie-chart you mentioned consist of two data series:

[image]

[Image source](https://towardsdatascience.com/improve-your-analytics-projects-w-these-data-distributions-visualizations-7ba3821f2092)

1. extract inner circle values as `List`

```
tempa = Values /@ Normal @ Values @ dsPie[Transpose]
(*Out: {{0.188111, 0.0394984}, {0.495803, 0.0639874}, ...} *)
```

2. Map `Total` on them to create outer circle:

```
b = Total /@ tempa
(*Out: {0.227609, 0.55979, 0.2126} *)
```

3. Coloring inner circle pairs + flattening the array

```
a = Flatten[{Style[#[[1]], LightOrange], Style[#[[2]], LightBlue]} & /@ tempa];
```

4. Define a function to do the labeling

```
labeler[v_, __] := Placed[{PercentForm[v, 3]}, {"RadialOuter"}]
```

4. Draw chart

```
PieChart[{a, b}, SectorOrigin -> {Automatic, 1}, LabelingFunction -> labeler, ChartStyle -> {LightRed, LightPurple, LightGreen}]
```

[image]

Whole code:

```
dsPie = Dataset[<|
   "Existing Customer" -> <|3 -> 0.188111, "More3" -> 0.495803, 
     "Less2incl" -> 0.155426|>, 
   "Attrited Customer" -> <|3 -> 0.0394984, "More3" -> 0.0639874, 
     "Less2incl" -> 0.0571739|>|>]

tempa = Values /@ Normal@Values@dsPie[Transpose]

b = Total /@ tempa

a = Flatten[{Style[#[[1]], LightOrange], Style[#[[2]], LightBlue]} & /@ tempa];

labeler[v_, __] := Placed[{PercentForm[v, 3]}, {"RadialOuter"}]

PieChart[{a, b}, SectorOrigin -> {Automatic, 1}, LabelingFunction -> labeler, ChartStyle -> {LightRed, LightPurple, LightGreen}]
```

Comment: So, using ```Style``` will override default choices for sector colors?

Comment: Yes. according to `ChartStyle` [documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ChartStyle.html):

"`Style[data,s]` can be used to style chart elements associated with individual data points or datasets. Such specifications are used after specifications from ChartStyle."

Answer (score 3):

```
dsPie = Dataset[<|
    "Existing Customer" -> <|
      3 -> 0.188111,
      "More3" -> 0.495803,
      "Less2incl" -> 0.155426|>,
    "Attrited Customer" -> <|
      3 -> 0.0394984,
      "More3" -> 0.0639874,
      "Less2incl" -> 0.0571739|>|>];

dsPie[d |-> PieChart[d,
   ChartLabels -> {Style[#, 14, 
        Bold] & /@ {"Existing     \nCustomers", 
       "Attrited      \nCustomers"}, Automatic},
   ChartLayout -> "Grouped",
   SectorOrigin -> {{-3 Pi/4, "Clockwise"}, 1/4},
   ImageSize -> 400]]
```

[image]

Comment: I like the in-line code, but I believe this chart does not fully reproduce the target. The inner chart should show both Attrited and Existing Customers, while the outer one shows the aggregation.