# How to display a circular data set?

Tags: data, dataset, visualization, style

Is there a straighftorward way of building the following plot

[image]

where 5 data sets are displayed circularly, and some specific regions are highlighted (indexed i to vi)?

Comment: How can there be a `straight`forward way of building a `circular` plot? :)

Comment: @Syed: You saved my day. Thanks :-))

Comment: This looks like a `SectorChart`. Assuming you have the underlying data, creating the initial `SectorChart` should be straight forward. Adding the colors and decorations will probably be tedious.

Comment: Search term: `Circos` quickly finds [this](https://medium.com/@Marianattestad/a-treatise-on-making-circos-plots-from-genomic-data-7ff496849e0) article. More inspiration [here](https://copyprogramming.com/howto/how-to-make-a-circular-heat-map-or-diagram-in-mathematica). I would say this is quite involved.

Comment: somewhat related [Insets around a clock](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/209657/125)?

Comment: also related: [How to make a circular heat map or diagram in Mathematica?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/242425/125)